# How to label a grouped bar chart using plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to add data labels to the tops of bar charts in plotly express.  I'm using two different columns from the data frame so I can't use the "colors" method.  I want to define "text" for each bar so it shows the data on top of the bar.  Here is an MRE.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

x = ['Aaron', 'Bob', 'Chris']
y1 = [5, 10, 6]
y2 = [8, 16, 12]

fig = px.bar(x=x, y=[y1,y2],barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

I tried:

```
fig = px.bar(x=x, y=[y1,y2],text=[y1,y2], barmode='group')
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using your setup, just add the following to the mix:

```
texts = [y1, y2]
for i, t in enumerate(texts):
    fig.data[i].text = t
    fig.data[i].textposition = 'outside'
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

x = ['Aaron', 'Bob', 'Chris']
y1 = [5, 10, 6]
y2 = [8, 16, 12]

fig = px.bar(x=x, y=[y1,y2],barmode='group')

texts = [y1, y2]
for i, t in enumerate(texts):
    fig.data[i].text = t
    fig.data[i].textposition = 'outside'
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

i found a answer that's is better.

Let's take as example this dictionary:

```py
data_dictionary = {
    "data_frame":{
        "x":["Aaron", "Bob", "Chris"],
        "y1":[5, 10, 6],
        "y2":[8, 16, 12]
    },
    "x":"x",
    "y":["y1", "y2"],
    "barmode":"group",
    "text":None,
    "text_auto":True
}
```

After that let's create a figure:

```py
fig = px.bar(
    **data_dictionary
)
```

If you tipe `fig.show()`, you'll se a graph simillary to the vestland's graph.

The only thing you need to do is to set text as None and text_auto as True.

I hope that helps you.